# C# Error: I am trying to modify my code to accept and return generic types for a school program

Tags: c#

I need to make my code accept and return generic types and arguments

```
interface sportsfan<out T> : visitor {
    T visit(NY ny) { // LINE 116
        Console.WriteLine("go to a Yankees game"); 
    }

    T visit(LA ca) {
        Console.WriteLine("go to a Dodgers game"); 
    }
}
```

I get the **Compile Time Error:**

> Genericvex0.cs(116,3): error CS0531: `sportsfan.visit(NY)':
> interface members cannot have a definition

Comment: what version of c# are you targetting?

Comment: whatever the most recent one is ; we are also using the extension MONO. Not sure if that's helpful or not

Comment: If you want to implement *default interface method* you should have C# **8** or later. If you use older version you can try doing the task (default implementation) with a help of *abstract class*

Comment: Typo? `T visit(NY ny)` method declaration means that it *returns* `T` instance: `T visit(NY ny) { Console.WriteLine("go to a Yankees game"); return SomeT; }   `

Comment: @ParhumE "whatever the most recent {version of C#} one is ; we are also using the extension MONO. " - that comment is very confusing - latest C# would be 9 or 10 (depending on if you count RC versions or not)  and version supported by Mono is something slightly below 7. And for code shown in the post to be plausible (default interface implementations) you need 8... Please [edit] question to clarify which is it.

Comment: First, please try to put some more effort into your questions, it's not that clear what you want or asked for. As some1 already mentioned you have to return a actual object of your type "T" for the methods. Aside of that you mentioned Mono which likely doesn't support C# 8 or higher and because of that you're not able to use default interface implementations. You therefor have to replace your methods with `T visit(NY ny);` and `T visit(LA ca);` only and let another class inherit your interface (you should also rename your interface to e.g. "ISportsFan" which is more common).

Answer (score 0):

Means what it says: interfaces can't have a body..Interfaces exist purely for polymorphism, so they simply contain method stubs and property definitions. Classes which implement your interfaces contain the implementation. The point is you might have an interface called IDrivable which has the method "DriveForward" then concrete classes (say Boat, Car) which both implement IDrivable, so have implementations of DriveForward.